# How to get full list of POS, Tag, and Dep in spaCy?

Tags: nlp, spacy

The POS, TAG, and DEP values used in spaCy are common ones of NLP, but I believe there are some differences depending on the corpus database.

For example, [Universal Dependencies Contributors](https://universaldependencies.org/en/dep/) has listed 37 syntactic dependencies. Does spaCy use all of these 37 dependencies? And nothing more?

Is there a command to output all POS, TAG, and DEP values, spaCy may provide?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A specific pipeline component can show its labels:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
nlp.get_pipe("tagger").labels
# ('$', "''", ',', '-LRB-', '-RRB-', '.', ':', 'ADD', 'AFX', 'CC', 'CD', 'DT', 'EX', 'FW', 'HYPH', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'LS', 'MD', 'NFP', 'NN', 'NNP', 'NNPS', 'NNS', 'PDT', 'POS', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS', 'RP', 'SYM', 'TO', 'UH', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT', 'WP', 'WP$', 'WRB', 'XX', '_SP', '``')
```

`spacy.explain(label)` will give a short definition for most labels, e.g.:

```
spacy.explain("NN")
# 'noun, singular or mass'
spacy.explain("PERSON")
# 'People, including fictional'
```

The detailed documentation is here: https://spacy.io/api/annotation

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, but maybe someone finds my answer helpful. I don't know if it is possible to output all POS, but they can be easily found here: [Part-of-Speech tagging](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#pos-tagging)

To get the list of DEP:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
for label in nlp.get_pipe("parser").labels:
    print(label, " -- ", spacy.explain(label))
```

To get the list of TAG:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
for label in nlp.get_pipe("tagger").labels:
    print(label, " -- ", spacy.explain(label))
```

The pipelines provided by spaCy are here: [Pipelines](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this link for dep_ list

https://github.com/clir/clearnlp-guidelines/blob/master/md/specifications/dependency_labels.md

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259)  so your fellow users will have some idea of what you try to say with providing this link.

Answer (score 1):

```
TAG_LIST = [".",",","-LRB-","-RRB-","``","\"\"","''",",","$","#","AFX","CC","CD","DT","EX","FW","HYPH","IN","JJ","JJR","JJS","LS","MD","NIL","NN","NNP","NNPS","NNS","PDT","POS","PRP","PRP$","RB","RBR","RBS","RP","SP","SYM","TO","UH","VB","VBD","VBG","VBN","VBP","VBZ","WDT","WP","WP$","WRB","ADD","NFP","GW","XX","BES","HVS","_SP"]
POS_LIST = ["ADJ", "ADP", "ADV", "AUX", "CONJ", "CCONJ", "DET", "INTJ", "NOUN", "NUM", "PART", "PRON", "PROPN", "PUNCT", "SCONJ", "SYM", "VERB", "X", "SPACE"]
DEP_LIST = ["acl", "acomp", "advcl", "advmod", "agent", "amod", "appos", "attr", "aux", "auxpass", "case", "cc", "ccomp", "compound", "conj", "cop", "csubj", "csubjpass", "dative", "dep", "det", "dobj", "expl", "intj", "mark", "meta", "neg", "nn", "npmod", "nsubj", "nsubjpass", "oprd", "obj", "obl", "pcomp", "pobj", "poss", "preconj", "prep", "prt", "punct",  "quantmod", "relcl", "root", "xcomp"]
NER_LIST = ["PERSON", "NORP", "FAC", "ORG", "GPE", "LOC", "PRODUCT", "EVENT", "WORK_OF_ART", "LAW", "LANGUAGE", "DATE", "TIME", "PERCENT", "MONEY", "QUANTITY", "ORDINAL", "CARDINAL"]
```

Comment: Your code seems to only show the answer but does not provide the answer to the "how" part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Python has built-in functions for inspecting objects like imported modules, classes, functions, lists and so on, simply type

dir(the object you are interested in)

to find the documenation you need about it.

Now, to find all the tags and their explanations in one go, we want to import spacy's glossary, like so

```
from spacy import glossary
```

and then we run

```
dir(glossary)
```

to get a list about the glossary-object:

```
['GLOSSARY',
 'Warnings',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
 'explain',
 'warnings']
```

At the very top, you see in capital letters GLOSSARY.

We type

```
glossary.GLOSSARY
```

and a long dictionary with GLOSSARY's keys and values appear (shorted by me):

```
{'ADJ': 'adjective',
 'ADP': 'adposition',
 'ADV': 'adverb',
 'AUX': 'auxiliary',
 'CONJ': 'conjunction',
...
}
```

Suppose we see some tags in code - SCONJ and CCONJ and more -, and we cannot be bothered to load the full GLOSSARY to find what SCONJ, CCONJ and the rest means, notice there were two more functions in the list returned by dir(glossary), explain and warnings.

We set a tag varible to be one of the mystery tags at a time, then use glossary's explain function to print out that part of GLOSSARY, like so

```
tag = 'SCONJ'
glossary.explain(tag)
```

and we get the result:

'subordinating conjunction'